# Save changes of textbox.text using entity in .net forms

Tags: c#, asp.net

So I'm trying to update a row in a database using the text from a textbox using .net forms.

On pageload I load the value and assign it to the text property of the textbox. Next I allow the user to change the text and click a button to upload, however the value in the database is not changed.

If I change the holter.companyName value to a static string the database updates. Also if I do not assign a companyNameTB.text value at pageloads the update button works as expected.

Any ideas?

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        PortalEntities db = new PortalEntities();
        var holterQuery = from holt in db.Holters
                          where holt.Id == 1
                          select holt;

        Holter holter = holterQuery.Single();

        string companyName = holter.CompanyName;
        CompanyNameTB.Text = companyName;

    }

    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        PortalEntities db = new PortalEntities();
        var holterQuery = from holt in db.Holters
                          where holt.Id == 1
                          select holt;


        Holter holter = holterQuery.Single();
        holter.CompanyName = CompanyNameTB.Text;
        holter.Id = 1;


        db.SaveChanges();



    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do this in the Page_Load method, otherwise the value in the textBox is refreshed to the original one at any page request (so the post back request too)

```
if(!Page.IsPostBack)
{
    PortalEntities db = new PortalEntities();
    var holterQuery = from holt in db.Holters
                      where holt.Id == 1
                      select holt;

    Holter holter = holterQuery.Single();

    string companyName = holter.CompanyName;
    CompanyNameTB.Text = companyName;
}
```

And you don't need this line is the Button1_Click method

```
holter.Id = 1;
```

Comment: Worked a treat, Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the Page_Load method is overwriting the textbox when the form is submitted. Put it inside of a conditional statement in order to check to see if the request is a post back, like so:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!Page.IsPostback)
    {
        PortalEntities db = new PortalEntities();
        var holterQuery = from holt in db.Holters
                          where holt.Id == 1
                          select holt;

        Holter holter = holterQuery.Single();

        string companyName = holter.CompanyName;
        CompanyNameTB.Text = companyName;
    }
}
```

This should allow the textbox to be populated from the database when the page is initially loaded, but then when the user submits the form that section of code should be skipped so that the new value in the textbox doesn't get overwritten.